# Parsing PHP file in order to get an array of parameters

Tags: php, parsing, tokenize, bitrix

I have a PHP file with following content:

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");

$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "hoo:account",
    "hoo",
    array(
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "hoo",
        "ACCOUNT_URL" => "/account/",
        "LOG_IN_URL" => "/log-in/",
        "FIELDS_REQUIRED" => array(
            0 => "FIRST_NAME",
            1 => "LAST_NAME",
            2 => "BIRTHDAY",
        ),
        "FIELDS_VALIDATED" => array(
            0 => "BIRTHDAY",
            1 => "COMPANY_VAT_CODE",
        ),
        "AGE_MIN" => "18",
        "AGE_MAX" => "180",
        "COMPANY_VAT_CODE_VALIDATION_SERVICE_CACHE_TTL" => "86400",
        "COMPANY_VAT_CODE_VALIDATION_SERVICE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR" => "Y",
        ...
    ), false);

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");
?>
```

Somehow I need to parse this file in order to get an associative array with parameters to use it somewhere else in my code. Please give me some ideas and code examples how to achieve that goal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have an associative array that you're passing into IncludeComponent. Just extract it and store it somewhere else so you can reference it where you need it. Where you store it is up to you.

Comment: @aynber it looks like an obvious solution but I want to keep it like this for a reason. To be more specific if I put an array in a separate variable editing component properties via CMS GUI stops working.

Comment: @ViacheslavRavdin please eaxplain better your last comment

Comment: [PHP Parser Library](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781786462879/9/ch09lvl1sec58/introduction-to-the-php-parser-library)

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this, unless the code you want to extract follows consistent formatting rules.

Comment: @Barman actually it does, function $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent has a third parameter which I want to extract...

Comment: The file starts with <? and not with <?php. If that is an oversight, please correct your code.

Comment: @lukas.j https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @ViacheslavRavdin Aren't they deprecated since PHP 7.4, and destined to be removed altogether?

Comment: @lukas.j I don't know to be honest but my CMS manufacturer requires this directive to be set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Tokenizer I was able to write a small parser to achieve my goal:

```
<?
$tokens = token_get_all();

$componentName = "hoo:account";

$arParams = array();

foreach ($tokens as $tokenKey => $token) {
    if (is_array($token)) {
        if (_getTokenName($token) == "T_STRING" &&
            _getToken($tokens, $tokenKey + 3) == $componentName
        ) {
            $isComponent = true;
        } elseif (_getTokenName($token) == "T_STRING" &&
                  _getToken($tokens, $tokenKey + 3) != $componentName
        ) {
            $isComponent = false;
        }

        if ($isComponent) {
            if (_getTokenName($token) == "T_DOUBLE_ARROW") {
                if (_getTokenName($tokens[$tokenKey - 2]) == "T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING") {
                    if (_getTokenName($tokens[$tokenKey + 2]) == "T_ARRAY") {
                        $key = _getToken($tokens, $tokenKey - 2);
                    } else {
                        $arParams[_getToken($tokens, $tokenKey - 2)] = _getToken($tokens, $tokenKey + 2);
                    }
                } elseif (_getTokenName($tokens[$tokenKey - 2]) == "T_LNUMBER") {
                    $arParams[$key][] = _getToken($tokens, $tokenKey + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function _getTokenName(array $token): string {
    return token_name($token[0]);
}

function _getToken(array $tokens, int $key): int | string {
    return trim($tokens[$key][1], "\"");
}
?>
```